# center label using place() in canvas tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to place label at the center using `place()` but when the text is changed its alignment shift to the right because of length of new word. How do I fix this using `place()`.

```
from tkinter import *

BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#B1DDC6"

# ------------------------------ UI --------------------------------------#
window = Tk()
window.title('Flashy')
window.config(padx = 50, pady = 50,bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR )



canvas = Canvas(window, width= 800, height = 626,bg = BACKGROUND_COLOR,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(row  = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
card_front_img = PhotoImage(file="./images/card_front.png")
canvas.create_image(400,263,image = card_front_img)
lang_label = Label(text   = 'French', font = ('Ariel',40,'italic'),anchor = CENTER)
lang_label.place(x = 300, y = 100)
word_label =Label(text = 'trouva', font = ('Arial',60,'bold'),anchor= CENTER)
word_label.place(x = 250, y = 200 )
window.mainloop()
```

Before:

```
word_label =Label(text = 'trouve', font = ('Arial',60,'bold'),anchor= CENTER)
word_label.place(x = 250, y = 200 )
```

[image]

After:

```
word_label =Label(text = 'trodawdauve', font = ('Arial',60,'bold'),anchor= CENTER)
word_label.place(x = 250, y = 200 )
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: please refer to line 29 in https://replit.com/@heysujal/RectangularFamousDisplaymanager#main.py

Comment: Links to code on other sites is discouraged here. If you want people to volunteer their time to help you, you should be willing to put in the time to include a proper example.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry, I will definitely keep this in mind from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `place`, you simply need to set the `anchor` attribute to `"n"` (north). That will cause the "north" (top-center) portion of the widget to be at the specified coordinates. Using `"s"` (south) or `"c"` (center)  would give a similar effect, though it changes which part of the label is at the given y coordinate.

```
lang_label.place(x = 250, y = 100, anchor="n")
word_label.place(x = 250, y = 200, anchor="n" )
```

No matter how long the text in `world_label` is, it will always be centered at the exact same point as `lang_label`.

Note: the x and y coordinates are just for illustrative purposes, you'll want to compute them to be the appropriate value for where you want them to be. The point being, if the x coordinate is the same, the labels will be centered with respect to each other.

Comment: @Sujal: I guarantee it works, because this is exactly how it is designed to work.

Comment: I think what OP said *"It doesn't work"* is because you used `x = 250` which is not at the center of the window.

Comment: @acw1668 . Yes that's exactly what happened.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative which works fine but doesn't use the `place()`
.By using `canvas.create_text()` instead of `place()` the text aligns itself in the centre irrespective of the length of the word

```
canvas.create_text(400,150, text='French', font=('Ariel', 40, 'italic'))
canvas.create_text(400,263, text='wordwdawdadawd', font=('Ariel', 60, 'bold'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a frame that's centered and then place the label onto it. Here's a great website that really helped me learn thinker: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm